# "There was a problem parsing the package" when uninstalling an app

Tags: google-play-store

I have Android phone which I flashed. Now, I want to download WhatsApp, but after downloading it, I can't open it. It continues to display "There was a problem parsing the package" when I try to uninstall the app, I can only disable it.

I'm trying to download again, but it is just showing me to update it, meaning that I still have the app on my phone. How to fix this?

Comment: Did you change the Android version when you flashed (e.g. did you move from Android 2.3 to Android 4.0 or something like that)?

Comment: What device do you have? And what Android version/custom ROM did you flash? Is it Moto G? If it is, there's a similar issue posted on [AndroidForums](http://androidforums.com/threads/anyone-else-gets-there-was-a-problem-parsing-the-package.797381/).

Answer (score 0):

This parsing error appers when either:

- The APK file is corrupted (unlikely if you're downloading from the Play Store)
- The APK file is not compatible with your Android version (again, unlikely if the Play Store works fine for other apps)

If the APK file is not provided by the Play Store, it is likely that either of these errors occur.